# C# forms too slow for a 2D game?

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine

I made this game with Python+Pygame, but it was slow, so I tried it with C# and its forms. It's even slower! I get only 20fps on a i5 radeon 6770m NTB millions of times faster than hardware I want this game to run and I haven't even finished the game yet, it's only rendering a map. It's a remake of a game that was run with slow several MHz processors. It's map containes 400x200 tiles and camera shows only 79*79. I also installed unity 4.5; is it worth learning it, would it bring me significant perfomance increase - if someone knows it how would I do a map consisting of 600*400 tiles randomly either dark tile or bright; it has to be "collidable"? Or I doing sth wrong in forms?

```
public void render()
    {

        Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        Graphics frameGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(frame);

        TextureID[,] textures = Background.Blocks;

        while (true)
        {

            //frameGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua), 0, 0, Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
            for (int x = 0; x < Game.AR_WIDTH; x++)
            {
                int xx = x * Game.TILE_SIDE - game.green_tank_pos[0] + Game.DIFF;
                if (xx < 0) continue;
                if (xx > Game.CANVAS_WIDTH) break;

                for (int y = 0; y < Game.AR_HEIGHT; y++)
                {
                    int yy = y * Game.TILE_SIDE - game.green_tank_pos[1] + Game.DIFF;
                    if (yy < 0) continue;
                    if (yy > Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT) continue;
                    switch(textures[x,y])
                    {
                        case TextureID.dark:
                            frameGraphics.DrawImage(tex_dark_gnd, xx, yy);
                            break;
                        case TextureID.bright:
                            frameGraphics.DrawImage(tex_bright_gnd, x * Game.TILE_SIDE - game.green_tank_pos[0] + Game.DIFF, y * Game.TILE_SIDE - game.green_tank_pos[1] + Game.DIFF);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            frameGraphics.DrawImage(tex_green_tank, Game.DIFF, Game.DIFF);



            drawHandle.DrawImage(frame, 0, 0);
```

Comment: GDI+ is not meant for video games.  Yes, it is on the slow side, use a proper graphics library (like Unity)

Comment: winforms isn't designed as a gaming platform.  You should use an *actual* gaming platform.

Comment: I just thought that Tunneler, no 3D game with shades, water, blah, blah, could be written with forms

Comment: @user3791837 Of course it *can* be written in forms, it could also be written in assembly. That doesn't mean it will be easy, or efficient, or is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinForms is a *terrible* platform for a game, even a 2D one. It was intended for line-of-business applications, and includes little to no hardware acceleration.

Plus the technology is just hard to write a game in, let alone an efficient one. You *might* get away with using WPF for a very simple game, but you will really want to learn XNA, MonoGame, Unity or some other actual game platform that can take advantage of DirectX (WPF does this as well, btw).

Comment: They say XNA is already dying with no successor. BTW how do you program games for Xbox One then? I'll use unity but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: @user3791837 XNA itself is dying, true, but there are lots of similar DirectX-based techs that you can use (Sunburn, NeoAxis, MonoGame all come to mind). As far as I know there is no "Indie game marketplace" for Xbox One, but I can't say I've looked all that hard either.

Comment: @user3791837 XNA is long dead yes. MonoGame is the open-source implementation of it. It's pretty much the same thing, but with support.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to get better performance drawing in winforms but for a game it's best to go with tools that better fit the job. (don't use a screwdriver to hit a nail).

The newer versions of Unity3D have built-in 2D tools. I'm personally building a 2D game in it and would highly recommend it.

**EDIT**: Removed my mention of XNA - I wasn't aware it was "dead".

Creating tiles in Unity3D can be done several ways

- Place sprites into the scene manually. Their locations and settings will be saved along with the scene.
- Place the sprites within the scene manually and create a prefab out of it. Thus, that set of tiles can be reused.
- Create a prefab of a single tile, and instantiate multiples of that prefab in a Behavior that is attached somewhere in a scene.

As for the rendering Unity3D will take care of that for you.

**EDIT2**: I created a short Unity3D behavior that you can attach somewhere inside your scene. This uses the 3rd approach I outlined above and it will pick randomly from a set of prefabs applied. This script assumes randomly picking from tiles and that the width of the tiles are 1 game unit wide/high.

1. Attach the behavior to something in the scene (like the main camera)
2. Create your tiles as prefabs
3. Drag the prefabs in the editor into the "Tile Prefabs" array on the behavior you've attached.
4. Set the "Tiles High" to 400 and "Tiles Wide" to 600
5. Set TileMapTopLeft to the top-left position you want it to start.
6. Run your scene.

Here's the behavior:

```
using UnityEngine;

class TileCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static System.Random rng = new System.Random();

    public GameObject[] TilePrefabs;

    public int TilesWide;

    public int TilesHigh;

    public Vector3 TileMapTopLeft;

    void Start()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < TilesWide; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < TilesHigh; y++)
            {
                Instantiate(TilePrefabs[rng.Next(TilePrefabs.Length)], new Vector3(x + TileMapTopLeft.x, y + TileMapTopLeft.y, TileMapTopLeft.z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably need to look up a tutorial on how to import resources and create prefabs but this script should get you in the right direction.

Comment: XNA is **not** a good option. It have been dead for over 2 years and can't be used in VS2012 without "hacks".

Comment: I have VS2013 and Unity. I don't know how to use Unity's GUI. How do I create a Canvas with tiles, that are repeating? Where is the code for rendering? How?

Comment: Like on start of the game I need a script that creates background objects.